# Improving Tesseract by preprocessing : removing non alphabetic (or alphanumeric) characters from an image

Tags: java, image-processing, tesseract

I'm trying to validate users uploaded documents by checking their content when uploaded, I'm using Tesseract for OCR, and bitap algorithm for fuzzy search to check if the keywords exit, everything work fine with simple documents (documents that contain simple text), but when I have some documents like this one : (I've kept only the concerned part)
[image]

The text isn't read, I get only some weird characters ...

But after removing the points under the text :

[image]

I get the exact text, so my question is , is it possible to do some image pre-processing to remove all non alphabetic (or alphanumeric) content? or is there any other solution? I'm sure there is since this [application](http://www.onlineocr.net) doesn't have any problem with extracting the content from the same doc, but I'm new to image processing, and I've found some answers in other programming languages explaining how to do that with OpenCV, any help/advice to solve this problem or to get better OCR result is welcome.
Thank you

Comment: You might want to look at the PageSegMode and try out different ones. Otherwise you should try to do some segmentation on the characters and use an operator that can remove the dots (erode, open). I use OpenCV in c++ for the image processing parts.

Comment: You could use [SWT](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/149305/1509.pdf) or [Extremal Regions](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/erfilter.html) methods for text detection. Then you could remove all the "noise" which is not classified as text area.